# sql - conditional query based on column on another table (date range)

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables here,
one is like a lookup table (session), one is a transaction table (transactions)

```
session     
id  start_time          end_time
1   2020-08-13 06:47:18 2020-08-13 18:48:42
2   2020-08-13 18:49:21 2020-08-14 06:52:31
```

```
transaction 
id  payment_time
1   2020-08-13 06:49:18
2   2020-08-13 06:54:11
3   2020-08-14 06:44:00
4   2020-08-14 06:47:37
```

How can I query to get below output, in which it can return the session based on the lookup table value?

```
end_result      
id  payment_time          session
1   2020-08-13 06:49:18    1
2   2020-08-13 06:54:11    1
3   2020-08-14 06:44:00    2
4   2020-08-14 06:47:37    2
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What if there is no session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.id AS id, t.payment_time, s.id AS session
FROM [session] s
INNER JOIN [transaction] t ON s.start_time <= t.payment_time AND s.end_time >= t.payment_time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
select T.id, T.payment_time, S.id
from [transaction] as T
inner join [session] as S on T.payment_time between S.start_time and S.end_time
```